# Trigger SharePoint Online List Workflow 2010 using the REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I am trying to trigger the SharePoint online List 2010 workflow.
But some how the I am able to trigger the 2013 workflow using the below code sample
Please help with how can i start the 2010 Workflow by using the Rest API of the by using the csom

```
    //StartWorkflow  
    function Start2013WFRestAPI(subscriptionId, itemID, workflowParams) { 

        var restURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/StartWorkflowOnListItemBySubscriptionId(subscriptionId='" + subscriptionId+ "',itemId='" + itemID + "')";

        $.ajax({  
                 url: restURL,  
                 type: "POST",  
                 contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                 headers: {  
                      "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                      "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()  
                 },  
                 success: function (data) {
                    alert('Workflow Trigger Successfully'); 

                 },  
                 error: function (data) {
                     alert("Error");  
                 }  
        });  

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You ever found the solution?

Comment: Try using this https://gist.github.com/Aymkdn/3873181